# What is the relationship between the various modules of the H2O?

Tags: java, h2o

I want to use H2O in my java application, but when I search in maven repository, there is several modules to be chosen.

```
h2o-core
h2o-genmodel
h2o-bindings
h2o-algos
h2o-automl
h2o-persist hdfs
...
```

What's the relationship of them?
Furthermore, I searched some examples, I found that I can train a data and get a model by using h2o-bindings or h2o-genmodel or h2o-algos.
Even that there are Classes that have same name in these modules, like DRFModel.

I'm really confused about how to use them.

Comment: For a JVM language user, I would recommend the Sparkling Water / Scala API rather than pure Java.  The pure Java API has almost no documentation and isn't really well supported for users, it's intended more for implementors (of H2O-3 itself).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use pure java. Because my project is a extension project which defined by other java project.

Comment: OK, you're probably going to have to rely on the source code quite a bit, then.  The documentation for doing this isn't great, but it has been done.  The junit tests are one source of examples.  Some people with corporate projects in this situation will become enterprise customers of (the company) H2O.ai because they want help.  [Disclosure:  I work for H2O.]